# Rasa deployment using Docker: Why no valid model found at /app/models?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, rasa

I’m trying to deploy my trained Rasa assistant as a web application running in multiple Docker containers on a VM. I'd like to use an existing model, so this is how I've configured the Rasa server:

My `docker-compose.yml` file (the relevant portion, at least):

```
version: '3'

services:

  rasa_server:

    container_name: "rasa_server"

    build:
      context: backend

    volumes:
      - ./backend:/app
      - ./backend/data:/app/data
      - ./backend/models:/app/models

    ports:
      - "5005:5005"
```

My `Dockerfile` for the `backend` context:

```
FROM rasa/rasa:3.3.1

WORKDIR /app

USER root

COPY ./data /app/data
COPY ./models /app/models
COPY . /app

ENTRYPOINT ["rasa", "run", "-m", "/app/models", "--enable-api", "--cors", "*", "--debug"]
```

Finally, here's the directory structure for the `backend` context:

```
|-- backend
|   |-- data
|   |   |-- nlu.yml
|   |   |-- rules.yml
|   |   |-- stories.yml
|   |-- models
|   |   |-- some_trained_model.tar.gz
|   |-- config.yml
|   |-- credentials.yml
|   |-- domain.yml
|   |-- endpoints.yml
|   |-- Dockerfile
```

Running `docker compose build` gives expected output. But when I run `docker compose up`, Rasa complains that it can't find a "valid model". Here are the last few lines of the log:

```
rasa_server     | 2023-04-08 00:34:58 INFO     rasa.core.processor  - Loading model /app/models/some_trained_model.tar.gz...
rasa_server     | /opt/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rasa/shared/utils/io.py:98: UserWarning: No valid model found at /app/models!
rasa_server     | 2023-04-08 00:34:58 INFO     root  - Rasa server is up and running.
```

Why does Rasa say the model isn't *valid*?